# how to show django messages without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, django

i was building a pop up signup form. and don't want to reload the page when it go to some error or success message. because then pop up form will get closed. i just want to show the message just there without reloading page.

this is what i am doing so far

views.py

```
def signup(request):

if request.method == "POST":

    username = request.POST["username"]
    email =  request.POST["email"].lower()
    password = request.POST["password"]
    password2 = request.POST["password2"]

    try:
        if password2 != password:
            messages.error(request, "password didn't match")
        elif len(password) < 6:
            messages.error(request, "password is too small.")
        elif User.objects.get(email=email):
            messages.error(request, "user with this email already exists")
    except:
        if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()):
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "User Created")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Looks like username already exists")

    django_messages = []

    for message in messages.get_messages(request):
        django_messages.append({
            "level": message.level,
            "message": message.message,
            "tags": message.tags, 
            })

    data = {}
    data['messages'] = django_messages

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit','#signup_form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"{% url 'auth_signup' %}",
        data:{

            'username':$('#signup_username').val()
            'email':$('#signup_email').val(),
            'password':$('#signup_password').val(),
            'password2':$('#signup_password2').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success:function(data){
            update_messages(data.messages);;
            $(".message").show();

        },

        error:function(data){
            update_messages(data.messages);
            (".message").show();


        }
    });
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update_messages(messages){
$("#msgs").html("");
$.each(messages, function (i, m) {
            $("#msgs").append("<div class='alert "+m.tags+"''><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>"+m.message+"</div>");});}</script>
```

when i press submit button.
it should have show error or success message right there. but 
page go to url http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup  and show only this json string.

{"messages": [{"level": 40, "message": "password didn't match", "tags": "alert-danger"}]}

Comment: Can you show the "signup" view? Are you aware that if you use ajax you need to write a view that gets the message and sends something back? If you do not need any access to the database you do not need to use ajax but just handle everything in JS browserside.

Comment: @ger.s.brett i already have attached my signup view .lookup there is a function call signup . that is my signup view